# Access data based by http middleware

Tags: go

Using this https://github.com/praveen001/go-passport

Path with passsport middleware:

```
app.Put("/api/auth/login", p.Authenticate("local", MyHandler))
```

The passport authenticate function:

```
// Authenticate calls `Strategy.Authenticate` method of registered strategies, and checks the `passport.Result` returned by it.
//
// The result is stored in the request context with `passport.CtxKey` as key.
//

func (p *Passport) Authenticate(name string, h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        s, ok := p.Options.strategies[name]
        if !ok {
            w.WriteHeader(404)
            return
        }

        s.Authenticate(w, r, func(res *Result) {
            res.StrategyName = name
            
            ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), CtxKey, res)
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
        })
    }
}
```

So this attach the response from my auth method and returns a http.HandleFunc which I can define myself (`MyHandler`).

```
func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Where is the data attached from the Authenticate func?
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(401)
    io.WriteString(w, `{"status":"ok"}`)
}
```

I dont understand where I can reach the attached data from the `Authenticate` func. The comment says: "//The result is stored in the request context with `passport.CtxKey` as key".

I don't find it in the `r *http.Request`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http.Request` object has a [`Context()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Context) method which gives you the context. You access the key through that.

E.g.

```
ctx := r.Context()
value := ctx.Value(passport.CtxKey)
```